# Doesn't change the previously sent file in Telegram using the API

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I send File Test.pdf on telegram by Telegram API. After several minutes, I have to do some editing in Test.pdf file and send it again.
But at this moment the telegram sends previous Test.pdf file, without my edition.
It seems telegram catched my url link and no longer checks the file for Changes. How can I clear or remove cached of sent file from telegram server and send changed file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what is happening. As far as I know only possible way would be to chose a different file name, so your URL will change too.

Another solution is to upload files via multipart/form-data instead of URL link. See https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#senddocument. Or refer to your specific Bot library, should you use one.